# Any other reason forEach() is provided a reference to the array itself aside from scoping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the callback provided to the `forEach` function is given 3 parameters: `currentValue`, `index`, `array`.

I'm trying to understand the purpose the `forEach` callback is provided the reference to the `array` itself as the 3rd parameter and the only reason I can see why is because of scoping.

1st Example:

```js
function printLastName(value, index, array) {
  if (index === (array.length - 1)) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

function setupNames() {
  const names = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  names.forEach(printLastName);
}

setupNames();
```

What I wish to illustrate in the 1st example above is that `printLastName()` used as the `forEach()` callback does not have a reference to the original `names` array and thus, if it needs to use the array, it needs to be provided the `3rd parameter`, hence the only reason I see why the `forEach` callback is provided a reference to the original `array`.

2nd Example:

```js
function setupNames() {
  const names = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  names.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    if (index === (names.length - 1)) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
}

setupNames();
```

In the 2nd example, the line `(index === (names.length - 1))`, I could have either used `names` or `array` since it's available to me. And to my understanding, there is absolutely no difference using either one.

To wrap it up, here's my question:

1. The `callback` to the `forEach` method is provided the `array` as the `3rd parameter` solely because of scoping issue (1st Example) and not for any other reason, correct?
2. In the 2nd example, there is absolutely no difference between me using `names` or `array` in the lambda callback to `forEach` **no matter** what the lambda callback logic is, correct?

Comment: This first example is a _sufficient_ use-case for why someone thought it was useful to add.. as such, it is both “explained” and “opinionated” (as this functionality is not a _requirement_ or available in all similar API).

Comment: To be precise the _question_ isn’t opinionated; APIs can definitely be, however so to rationalize such other than “that is how it’s defined” outside of considering if such is sufficient can reflect such.

Comment: 1) It was an API decision; 2) They are semantically the same in the code shown: both names (variable caught in closure and parameter) refer to / evaluate to the same array object.

Comment: "*no difference between using `names` or `array`, no matter what the lambda callback logic is*" - well, except when the logic does overwrite one of these variables but not the other one :-)

Comment: @Bergi if you manipulate either `names` or `array`, the other variable is affected too, hence its the same, yes?

Comment: @user2864740 I follow your logic and agree, thanks

Comment: @ThaneshR No. If you manipulate the array's properties, both are the same, but if you re-assign the variable the other is not affected.

Comment: @Bergi I just did some test and you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this use-case recently which made me understand why the array parameter can be useful (when I previously didn't see the usefulness of it either).

Consider:

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'John Paul', 'John Smith', 'James'];

names.filter(n => n.startsWith('John')).forEach((john, index, array) => {
   // If it's not the first or last entry, then we want to write it to console
   if (index !== 0 || index !== array.length - 1) console.log(john);
});
```

If you are creating a new collection as the result of a `.filter` etc, then the new collection won't be available as a reference if written as above. The array parameter provides you access to the collection that you are iterating with `.forEach`.

Comment: To be precise, the `forEach` 3rd param variable `array` and the `names` variable are not equivalent in this example. However, I'm marking this as correct because it illustrates an example of why the `forEach` callback method definition includes the 3rd param (aside from scoping), which is the underlying reason I posed this question in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All features come from specifications and proposals, so going into the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach).

It does not seem to have a very specific reason to exist. But as you say, when analysing different examples that may use `forEach` it makes sense that it is due to scoping. For example, when defining a generic function like:

`function calculateSomethingThatNeedsLookupInTheArray(val, index, array`. It will be much more tight in implementation if we only rely on the context, that if we just refer to the array that uses this function.

```
const array1 = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
const array2 = [1, 2]

array1.forEach((val) => {
 something(val / array1[0]))
array2.forEach((val) => {
 something(val, array2[0]))
```

vs

```
const array1 = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
const array2 = [1, 2]

const operationCallback = (val, i, array) => {
 something(val /array[0])
} 

array1.forEach(operationCallback)
array2.forEach(operationCallback)
```

Also remember, we can pass any context to forEach apart from the callback, known as `thisArgument`, what highlights the importance of keeping the array to scope or target the current array we are using.

Comment: It is difficult to come with pragmatic examples of when do you need a reference to the original array and not related with reduction / folding kind of operations than I thought :D

Comment: "*Most of this new features*" - `forEach` is everything but a new feature.

Comment: Sorry, i refered to all features :p